# Handling single file in Promise.all with map

Tags: node.js

I have an async function, that right now only handles arrays, i would like to change this function so that it can handle a single file.

```
const items = await file.map(async url => {
  const id3Data = await getId3Data(url);
  return Object.assign({}, { url }, id3Data)
});
```

How would i change this so i can just take a single file instead.
When i upload a file, its being uploaded one at a time, would a quick fix maybe be to put that file string into an array and that would solve the issue maybe?

Comment: The simplest solution: pass an array that contains a single file?

Comment: Otherwise, just drop the `map()` wrapper

Comment: I think probably the easiest fix is to just pass an array with a single file.

Comment: Yes, do that. If it doesn't work, please post more of your code.